# alt tag is not getting removed even after doing $image->removeAttribute('alt')?

Tags: php, dom, image

I want to remove alt tag from all the  tags present within an HTML file. Actually it is removing alt for many of the tags but not for few . I couldn't understand why? can anybody help me. Thx in advance. 
Below is my code to remove ,  and  :

```
function get_clear_data($html){
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->loadHTML($html);

        foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
        {
            $image->removeAttribute('alt');
            $image->removeAttribute('xmlns');
            $image->removeAttribute('title');
        }

                $final_data=$dom->saveHTML();

                return $final_data;
}
```

The sample of the HTML  tag is as follows :

```
<img align="middle" alt="«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«mo»§#8712;«/mo»«/math»" class="Wirisformula" src="/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=811d8a98dc8c17603bbb0d65bece4423.png" title="Double click to edit"> R define <img align="middle" alt="«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mi»z«/mi»«/msup»«mo»=«/mo»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mi»x«/mi»«/msup»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»(«/mo»«mi mathvariant=¨normal¨»cos«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»y«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»+«/mo»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»i«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi mathvariant=¨normal¨»sin«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»y«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»)«/mo»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi mathvariant=¨normal¨»sin«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»z«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»=«/mo»«mfrac»«mn»1«/mn»«mrow»«mn»2«/mn»«mi»i«/mi»«/mrow»«/mfrac»«mo»(«/mo»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mrow»«mi»i«/mi»«mi»z«/mi»«/mrow»«/msup»«mo»-«/mo»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mrow»«mo»-«/mo»«mi»i«/mi»«mi»z«/mi»«/mrow»«/msup»«mo»)«/mo»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»a«/mi»«mi»n«/mi»«mi»d«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi mathvariant=¨normal¨»cos«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mi»z«/mi»«mo»§nbsp;«/mo»«mo»=«/mo»«mfrac»«mn»1«/mn»«mn»2«/mn»«/mfrac»«mo»(«/mo»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mrow»«mi»i«/mi»«mi»z«/mi»«/mrow»«/msup»«mo»+«/mo»«msup»«mi»e«/mi»«mrow»«mo»-«/mo»«mi»i«/mi»«mi»z«/mi»«/mrow»«/msup»«mo»)«/mo»«/math»" class="Wirisformula" src="/ckeditor_3.6.1//plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage.php?formula=7044dd31440f7c753195b5b5e09ba431.png" title="Double click to edit">
```

Comment: can you show the mark-up you are running the function on?

Comment: yes I've added the sample HTML code.

Comment: running your function on your html sample for me removes `alt` and `title` attributes. would need a larger sample to see what's going on i think.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is maybe the HTML has some invalid code in it which is throwing the dom parser. Have you checked the validity of your code using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: works for me; proof: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8a6c453dbc64794b37cac039f734a3384abefd5

Answer (score 0):

Works for both images. Do you store the html in a variable and then pass it to the method?